# The package java.util.logging is not accessible in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying run simple hello word java program and want to log hellow world.
But I am getting error as

"The package java.util.logging is not accessible" on the statement
`import java.util.logging.*;` in eclipse.

I am using Java 11 version

Complete code below

```java
    package myproject;

    import java.io.Console;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Logger; 
    import java.util.logging.*;    

    public class FileOperations {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create a Logger 
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileOperations.class.getName());

            // Call info method 
            logger.info("This is message 1");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File file=new File("myFile.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos;

            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(2);
                System.out.println("File operation completed");
                Logger.log(Level.INFO, "My first Log Message"); 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code for us to check? This gives us better info on how to help you.

Comment: Are you using modules (do you have a module-info.java)?

Comment: yes while creating java project it has created one file called module.info.. which contains                                                                                                     
 module myproject {
}        i dont know much about module file :S

Comment: If you are using modules, you must requires java.logging.

Comment: u mean inside module file i need to add that?

Comment: `module myproject { requires java.logging; }`

Comment: Read something like [this](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)

Answer (score 14):

If you have a module-info.java file, then add

```
requires java.logging;
```

Comment: it worked, how did this solve the problem? can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with creating a Logger object?

`Logger logger = Logger.Leve`

It seems that it is not completed.

Comment: It is the 'import' which is not working - because the Java module system is not allowing it.